# Django - Giving a view access to multiple models

Tags: django

I followed a tutorial on Youtube that makes a website to create posts. Currently, I am working on displaying other people's profiles and their posts on their profile pages. I did it by accessing the author of the first post, but it only works if the user posted something. Is there another way to do it?

[image]

[image]

The view:

```
class UserProfileView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_profile.html'    # defaults to <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html--> blog/post_list.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'   #defaults to objectlist
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

user_profile.html:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ view.kwargs.username }}'s Profile{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media">
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ posts.first.author.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ posts.first.author.email }}</p>
                <p class="article-content">{{ posts.first.author.profile.bio }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if posts.first.author == user %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary ml-2" href="{% url 'change_profile' %}">Edit Profile</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <br>
    {% if posts.first.author == user %}
        <h3 class="ml-2 article-title">Blogs You Posted</h3>
    {% else %}
        <h3 class="ml-2 article-title">Blogs By {{ view.kwargs.username }}</h3>
    {% endif %}
```

And the Post and Profile module:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, default='')


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            img.thumbnail((300,300))
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably don't need `.first` in your `template`, because you are using the first item from the `QuerySet`. If you are accessing a `User profile`, you can use the `DetailView`. In addition, you can try from a different page and provide `filtered posts` in `context`. Something like this, for example.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(author=user) # from kwargs
    return context

#template
<ul>
{% for post in posts %}
    <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
    <li>{{ post.content }}</li>
    <li>{{ post.date_posted }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

PS Regards to Corey.

Comment: I understand the `get_context_data` part, but I can't figure out how would I change the view, can you please explain more.

Comment: First, did you notice a significant improvement after deleting the `.first` from the template?

Comment: After deleting `.first`, everything else works fine except the email, and it still only works if the user posted something

Comment: Describe it in more detail and add a screenshot.